# Python pyqt6 window blocks main loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, pyside6

I have a small program that does something, but i want to "switch modes", for now i press a key and an input prompts on the console, but to make it easier i want to make a window with pyqt6, the problem is that the window blocks or halts the main loop while it's open, i tried with threading/multiprocessing but i can't make it work.

```py
import threading
from queue import Queue

from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

queue = Queue()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel("Change modes")
        btn1 = QPushButton("MODE 1")
        btn2 = QPushButton("MODE 2")
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(btn2)    
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.mode1)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.mode2)
        self.show()

    def mode1(self):
        queue.put("mode1")

    def mode2(self):
        queue.put("mode2")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec()

    mode = "none"

    while True:

        _mode = queue.get()
        if mode != _mode:
            mode = _mode;
            print(f"mode: {mode}")

        # do stuff here
```

the only way that the while loop executes is when i close the window.

Comment: It's not the window blocking, it's the application event loop, which is essential for almost any UI based toolkit to let it process user and system events (user input, window drawing, etc). If you want to do repetitive operations, use QTimer, if you need to communicate with external sources (eg: network replies), use QThread or the appropriate Qt API. Unfortunately, your "a small program that does something" is completely insufficient to understand what you want to do, so please [edit] your question and clarify what you are *actually* doing. Also, please use proper tags: PyQt is *not* PySide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional Python multiprocessing/multithreading libraries such as `multiprocessing` and `threading` do not work well with Qt-like (`PyQt` and `PySide`) graphical programs. Fortunately, among other solutions, `PySide` provides the `QThread` interface, allowing multithreading in `PySide` graphical interfaces. It can be applied to your program as follows:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue

from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QThread

queue = Queue()

class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        mode = "none"

        while True:

            _mode = queue.get()
            if mode != _mode:
                mode = _mode;
                print(f"mode: {mode}")

            # do stuff here


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel("Change modes")
        btn1 = QPushButton("MODE 1")
        btn2 = QPushButton("MODE 2")
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(btn2)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.mode1)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.mode2)
        self.show()

        self.worker = Worker()  # Create a Worker instance
        self.worker.start()  # Start the Worker instance (which calls the run function of the Worker instance)

    def mode1(self):
        queue.put("mode1")

    def mode2(self):
        queue.put("mode2")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.worker.terminate()  # When the window closes, stop the thread

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

Please note the changed import statement of `PySide6.QtCore` (to import `QThread`), the addition of the `self.worker` variable in the `__init__` function of the `MainWindow` class (to actually start the thread), as well as the addition of a `closeEvent` function in the `MainWindow` class (to terminate the thread when the window closes).